# How do you show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

This is a simple proof of Real Analysis.
Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=0$, given $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0$.

How do you show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=0$?

I tried by myself  $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\delta\implies |g(x)|<\epsilon.$ Since $g(x) \leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ 
By squeeze theorem. I think  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0$

Comment: You know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Like this $$|lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)| ≤ |lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)|$$

Comment: $$|lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)| ≤ 0$$  $$0≤ lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) ≤ 0$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use the squeeze theorem first to show that the limit of $|f(x)|$ must be nonnegative, and since $g$ approaches 0 as $x$ approaches $a$ and $g(x)\geq |f(x)|$, then $|f(x)|$ tends to $0$  as $x$ approaches $a$, and then to show that the limit of the absolute value of a function approaches zero as $x$ approaches $a$ implies the original function approaches zero as $x$ approaches $a$ can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799115/limit-of-the-absolute-value-of-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:|a-x|<\delta\implies |g(x)|<\epsilon.$ Since $|f(x)|\leq g(x)\leq |g(x)|$ it follows
$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:|a-x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|\leq |g(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Is it right |f(x)|≤g(x)≤|g(x)|?. I dont see where it comes from

Comment: mag From here |f(x)|≤g(x),It looks more like 
   -g(x) ≤f(x)≤g(x)

Comment: Yes, it comes from $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$, what you assumed to hold in your question. And the next step $g(x) \leq |g(x)|$ is obvisous, I think.

Comment: Without the assumption $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$, the statement of your question wouldn't hold.

Comment: mag. Thank you for your kind and humble answer. I had a bad experience related to other people. I m not going to mention nothing else but thank you. This is what I need to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $\forall x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta),g(x)<\varepsilon$ because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=0$. Thus $\forall x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta),|f(x)|\leqslant g(x)<\varepsilon$ so that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=0.$